# no suitable method found for add(long)

Tags: java, list, types, hashmap

no suitable method found for add(long)!

I know this problem is arising because of usage of Long and long but-
How to resolve this issue when it i want to take my x and y arrays as long in some coding question!

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int T=sc.nextInt();
for(int it=0;it<T;it++){
    int N=sc.nextInt();
    long x[]=new long[N];//////
    long y[]=new long[N];//////

    HashMap<Long,List<Long>> hh=new HashMap<>();////////////
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        x[i]=sc.nextLong();///
        y[i]=sc.nextLong();///
        List<Long>ll=new ArrayList<>();////
        if(hh.get(x[i])==null){
            ll.add(y[i]);//*error
            hh.put(x[i], ll);//*error
        }else{
            ll=hh.get(x[i]);
            ll.add(y[i]);//*error
            hh.put(x[i], ll);//*error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. And you can put `long` in a `List<Long>`.

Comment: what is the java version?

Comment: I am using Java version 8

Comment: List<long> gives unexpected type error

Comment: _List<long> gives unexpected type error_ - Use `List<Long>` instead of `List<long>`.

Comment: Here is a link to [autoboxing] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Consider this code for my doubt:-                                             
                                                                                                  
Map<Long,Integer> hh=new HashMap<Long,Integer>();
            long xx=1234;
            hh.put(xx,12);//long cannot be converted to Long error here!                         
                                                                                                                           
This long is not getting converted to Long ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the solution:- java.lang.Long solved the issue but still don't know the reson.

```
HashMap<java.lang.Long,List<java.lang.Long>> hh=new HashMap<>();////////////
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    x[i]=sc.nextLong();///
    y[i]=sc.nextLong();///
    List<java.lang.Long>ll=new ArrayList<>();////
    if(hh.get(x[i])==null){
        ll.add(y[i]);//*error
        hh.put(x[i], ll);//*error
    }else{
        ll=hh.get(x[i]);
        ll.add(y[i]);//*error
        hh.put(x[i], ll);//*error
    }
}
```